# Simulation to generate balanced longitudinal data

Tags: r

I want to do some simulation in R, I have written a code but I am not getting any headway. I will be grateful if anyone could help. I want to generate longitudinal data for three time points with different observations such that for any 1000 simulations it generates different observations. Note that the data should be balanced. equal number of TRT and Placebo at each time point. I am really struggling with it. Any help will be well appreciated. Below is the code;

```
ns=20
x1=rnorm(ns,0,1)
x2=rnorm(ns,5,5)
x3=rnorm(ns,10,5)
U=c(x1,x2,x3)
ans=matrix(rep(0,200),nrow=100)
for(k in 1:100)
{   simdata=data.frame(CD=U,
                       Time=factor(rep(c(1,2,3),each=ns)),
                       treatment=sample(rep(c('Trt','placebo'),ns/2)))
ans[k,]=table(simdata$treatment)
}
```

Comment: I tried to clean up your code, but I'm not sure I interpreted correctly. Feel free, to correct.

Comment: You need to describe more clearly how you want to simulate. If you do that, writing the simulation should be quite simple. In school, I was taught to draw a flow chart of an algorithm before writing code. I think that would help you.

Comment: Roland thanks so much. I want to include a code that does about 1000 simulations such that each simulation gives different set of observations. any idea as to how this is done?

Comment: Now with the data frame created I want to do simulation 1000 times such that each simulation gives different observations for time 1, different observations for time 2 and different for time 3. I also wish to write a code such that I can call only observations at time point 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (you can scale it up as required)

```
### no. simulations (2 per timepoint)
ns <- 2
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
### ns*2 as each time has both Tx and plac~ elements
    time = rep(seq(3), each=ns*2),
### ns*3 as 3x time points
    tx = rep(c("tx", "pl"), ns*3),
### ns*2 as each simulation performed for Tx and plac~
    sim = c(rnorm(ns*2, 0, 1), rnorm(ns*2, 5, 5), rnorm(ns*2, 10, 5))
    )
```

giving:

```
   time tx        sim
1     1 tx -0.6264538
2     1 pl  0.1836433
3     1 tx -0.8356286
4     1 pl  1.5952808
5     2 tx  6.6475389
6     2 pl  0.8976581
7     2 tx  7.4371453
8     2 pl  8.6916235
9     3 tx 12.8789068
10    3 pl  8.4730581
11    3 tx 17.5589058
12    3 pl 11.9492162
```

then you can subset as required e.g.

```
df1[df1$time==1, ]
```

**Edit** If you prefer, you can sort/order the `data.frame` to have `tx` and `plac` separated with

```
df1[order(df1$tx), ]
```

I don't see the need for a loop here; you can just expand the no. of samples `ns`; using `rnorm` you'll get *random* no.s for any sample size. (Or you could repeat generating the `data.frame` 1000 times and store the results (they'll all be different as long as the seed is not reset), but this is much less efficient).

Comment: Thanks Dardisco. I see I can now call the observations for only time point but I do not want the tx and plac to be following each other as you have in your code. Now I specifically need a loop in the code such that for 1000 simulations my observations will be different for all the time points.